# Javascript for-loops for calculations

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, dom

is there a clean way to do multiple calculations with for-loops? My javascript program has a few tables (workouts) consisting of exercises and the amount of repetitions. The user can change the difficulty by clicking for example the button 25%. It then multiplies the number of repetitions by 0.25, dropping it to a quarter.

Now I have done this multiplication manually, but as there becomes more tables it becomes painful. Any ideas using for-loops? The ID:s are unique.

```
let difficulty = 1

// Initializing default values 100 %

document.querySelector("#edJumpingJacks").innerHTML = 200;
document.querySelector("#edSquat").innerHTML = 100;

// Eventlisteners for difficulty

document.querySelector("#dif25").addEventListener("click", dif25);
document.querySelector("#dif50").addEventListener("click", dif50);
document.querySelector("#dif75").addEventListener("click", dif75);
document.querySelector("#dif100").addEventListener("click", dif100);

function dif25(){
    difficulty = 0.25;
    document.querySelector("#edJumpingJacks").innerHTML = (200 * difficulty).toFixed(0);
    document.querySelector("#edSquat").innerHTML = (100 * difficulty).toFixed(0);
}
function dif50(){
    difficulty = 0.50;
    document.querySelector("#edJumpingJacks").innerHTML = (200 * difficulty).toFixed(0);
    document.querySelector("#edSquat").innerHTML = (100 * difficulty).toFixed(0);
```

Comment: When event occurs, change the value of `difficulty` and call the same function each time. No need to duplicate functions

Answer (score 0):

It's always important to keep your code as simple and readable as possible. I would therefore simplify most of your code, except for the buttons itself (unless you plan to create *a lot* of them).

---

Create an array containing your element ids:

```
let ids = ['edJumpingJacks', 'edSquat'];
```

Change your click handlers to support just one function with a difficulty param:

```
document.querySelector("#dif25").addEventListener("click", diff(25));
document.querySelector("#dif50").addEventListener("click", diff(50));
document.querySelector("#dif75").addEventListener("click", diff(75));
document.querySelector("#dif100").addEventListener("click", diff(100));
```

In your function, loop over your ids array:

```
function diff (diff) {
    difficulty = diff;
    ids.forEach(function(id) {
        document.querySelector("#" + id).innerHTML = (200 * difficulty ).toFixed(0);
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more generic way. all your click elements have the difficulty in their id's and all they need to do is pass that id to the click handler.

```
var difficulties = [25, 50, 75, 100];
for (var i = 0; i< difficulties.length; i++) {
    document.querySelector("#dif" + difficulties[i]).addEventListener("click", calculateDifficulty(difficulties[i]));
}

function calculateDifficulty(difficulty) {
    return function(e) {
        document.querySelector("#edJumpingJacks").innerHTML = (200 * difficulty).toFixed(0);
        document.querySelector("#edSquat").innerHTML = (100 * difficulty).toFixed(0);
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You better use only one generic function to calculate the difficulty and append it to the elements, then use this generic function on the `click` event of your buttons.

This is how should be your code:

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("#dif25, #dif50, #dif75, #dif100")).forEach(function(btn) {
  btn.onclick = function() {
    diff(parseInt(btn.id.match(/(\d+)$/)[0]));
  }
});

function diff(difficulty) {
  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("#edJumpingJacks, #edSquat")).forEach(function(el) {
    el.textContent = (200 * difficulty).toFixed(0);
  });
}
```

**Explanation:**

Where `document.querySelectorAll("#dif25, #dif50, #dif75, #dif100")` will match all the buttons, and then attach the event to them dynamically.

And inside your `diff` function get all the elements that needs to be updated with `document.querySelectorAll("#edJumpingJacks, #edSquat")`.

Note that you better use `el.textContent` to change the content of the elements instead of using `.innerHTML` which is used to change the HTML content.

**Demo:**

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("#dif25, #dif50, #dif75, #dif100")).forEach(function(btn) {
  btn.onclick = function() {
    diff(parseInt(btn.id.match(/(\d+)$/)[0]));
  }
});

function diff(difficulty) {
  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("#edJumpingJacks, #edSquat")).forEach(function(el) {
    el.textContent = (200 * difficulty).toFixed(0);
  });
}
```

```html
<button id="dif25">dif25</button>
<button id="dif50">dif50</button>
<button id="dif75">dif75</button>
<button id="dif100">dif100</button>

<div id="edJumpingJacks">200</div>
<div id="edSquat">100</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the super fast answers. This solution works perfectly for the multiplication.

One minor problem came around. At the end of the code I give the pressed difficulty-button a CSS-class and make the others grey. With this solution **console log is always 25 for each button**. Any advice on that?

**Edit.** I figured it out. Must use double equal signs in the if-statement. Now it works perfectly. And the code shrunk from 130 lines to 60 lines. Sweet!

```
// Initializing default values 100 %

document.querySelector("#edJumpingJacks").innerHTML = 200;
document.querySelector("#edSquat").innerHTML = 100;
document.querySelector("#edMountainClimber").innerHTML = 90;
document.querySelector("#edSitUp").innerHTML = 80;
document.querySelector("#edJumpOverPlank").innerHTML = 70;
document.querySelector("#edPushUp").innerHTML = 60;
document.querySelector("#edLunge").innerHTML = 50;
document.querySelector("#edPullUp").innerHTML = 40;

// Eventlisteners for difficulty

let difficulties = [25, 50, 75, 100];
for (let i = 0; i< difficulties.length; i++) {
    document.querySelector("#dif" +difficulties[i]).addEventListener("click", calculateDifficulty(difficulties[i]));
}

function calculateDifficulty(difficulty) {
    return function(e) {

    document.querySelector("#edJumpingJacks").innerHTML = (200 * (difficulty /100)).toFixed(0);
    document.querySelector("#edSquat").innerHTML = (100 * (difficulty /100)).toFixed(0);
    document.querySelector("#edMountainClimber").innerHTML = (90 * (difficulty / 100)).toFixed(0);
    document.querySelector("#edSitUp").innerHTML = (80 * (difficulty / 100)).toFixed(0);
    document.querySelector("#edJumpOverPlank").innerHTML = (70 * (difficulty / 100)).toFixed(0);
    document.querySelector("#edPushUp").innerHTML = (60 * (difficulty / 100)).toFixed(0);
    document.querySelector("#edLunge").innerHTML = (50 * (difficulty / 100)).toFixed(0);
    document.querySelector("#edPullUp").innerHTML = (40 * (difficulty / 100)).toFixed(0);

    // Change active difficulty button
    if (difficulty == 25){
        document.querySelector("#dif25").className = "ui green label";
        document.querySelector("#dif50").className = "ui grey label";
        document.querySelector("#dif75").className = "ui grey label";
        document.querySelector("#dif100").className = "ui grey label";
    } else if (difficulty == 50){
        document.querySelector("#dif25").className = "ui grey label";
        document.querySelector("#dif50").className = "ui yellow label";
        document.querySelector("#dif75").className = "ui grey label";
        document.querySelector("#dif100").className = "ui grey label";
    } else if (difficulty == 75){
        document.querySelector("#dif25").className = "ui grey label";
        document.querySelector("#dif50").className = "ui grey label";
        document.querySelector("#dif75").className = "ui orange label";
        document.querySelector("#dif100").className = "ui grey label";
    } else if (difficulty == 100){
        document.querySelector("#dif25").className = "ui grey label";
        document.querySelector("#dif50").className = "ui grey label";
        document.querySelector("#dif75").className = "ui grey label";
        document.querySelector("#dif100").className = "ui red label";
    }
};
}
```

Comment: In the future, it's better to put an update like this in the original question, instead of posting an answer. Welcome to stackoverflow!